# python - Convert Panda Dataframe string-column into bigquery.SchemaField "TIMESTAMP"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a `BigQuery Table` from a python panda `Dataframe`.

the csv file has the content:

```
t_time
2023-01-01 07:20:54.272000 UTC
2023-01-02 04:22:26.914000 UTC
2023-01-03 04:32:38.663000 UTC
```

the BigQuery table has one column `t_time` with datatype `TIMESTAMP`

schema: `bigquery.SchemaField("t_time", "TIMESTAMP", mode="NULLABLE")`

snippet code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import ... 
client = bigquery.Client()

df=pd.read_csv("./my_times.csv",  header=1, names=['t_time'])   
print(f"> {df['t_time']}")
df.info()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
  schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("t_time", "TIMESTAMP"),
  ]
  write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, "myproj.mydataset.mytable", job_config=job_config).result()
```

output:

```
    0     2022-08-03 07:20:54.272000 UTC
    1     2022-08-04 04:22:26.914000 UTC
    2     2022-08-03 04:32:38.663000 UTC
Name: t_time, dtype: object
Error object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int
```

The problem is in `bigquery.SchemaField("insert_timestamp", "TIMESTAMP"),`
I am wondering why, since I have other tables with timestamp format and  with times in that format`<date> <time> UTC`.

I have tried also to convert the dataframe column `t_time` to timestamp but without success (not sure hot to convert from that format into timestamp).

What would be the correct approach to have the `bigquery` table with datatype `timestamp` for the give CSV format (with UTC)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
client = bigquery.Client()
 
df=pd.read_csv("./csv_t_time - Sheet1.csv",  header=1, names=['t_time'])  
print(f"> {df['t_time']}")
 
job_config = bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig(
schema = [
 
   bigquery.SchemaField("t_time", "TIMESTAMP"),
  
],autodetect=False,
   source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,  write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",allow_quoted_newlines = True,
 
)
 
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, "myproj.mydataset.mytable", job_config=job_config).result()
```

To avoid the error you need to set `source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV` in job_config and while loading CSV with embedded newlines, you need to specify `allowQuotedNewlines=True`.For more information you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv).

Comment: Thnaks, the additional options `autodetect` and `source_format` make the difference!